# Suppress SSL warnings

Tags: java, ssl

Is there any way to supress SSL warning messages in java or weblogic I am getting this output from my java code which connects to SSL weblogic domain .I do not need this output.

```
 <May 6, 2013 8:15:11 PM GMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 

    <May 6, 2013 8:15:11 PM GMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 

    <May 6, 2013 8:15:11 PM GMT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=CertGenCA,OU=FOR TESTING ONLY,O=MyOrganization,L=MyTown,ST=MyState,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>
```

Comment: I suppose you can get rid of the first two warnings by specifying `-Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=false` and `-Dweblogic.security.alloCryptoJDefaultPRNG=false`. To eliminate the third warning, you need to delete the CertGenCA from your truststore (it's either located in the file ~/.truststore or at the location specified with -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore)

Comment: I need certificate I am communicating via SSL

Comment: Are you sure? The warning message indicates that the certificate is ignored.

Comment: yes I am using certificated hence i cannot remove them